# Replace placeholders in persistence.xml from properties file (without using spring)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, properties

At run-time take values from a properties file and replace them into persistence.xml. Is there anyway to easily achieve this? I was thinking of doing this in code itself (i.e read values from the properties file and replace it in persistence.xml; don't know if that will work, or is a good idea).

I think with spring it is possible but i am not using spring.

Comment: Do you mean compile-time (build time) or run-time?

Comment: replacing values at run time is not possible even with spring. At run time you will need parameters to make a decision which values to select for your persistence.xml

Comment: You can use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer to achieve that using Spring.